# 1.You are trying to guess a three-letter password that uses only the letters A, E, I, O, U, and Y.

Tags: probability

Letter can be used more than once. Find the probability that you guess the correct password :You

Comment: Like $\dfrac{1}{6^3}$?

Comment: That assumes of course that either you guessed uniformly at random or the password itself was selected uniformly at random from the available passwords.

Comment: @Tanya Welcome to Maths Stack Exchange. The contributors here have no issue with helping you with homework problems, but please show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $6$ possible letters, meaning that there are

$$
6 \times 6 \times 6=216
$$

possible combinations. If you randomly guess a password, then the chance of you correctly guessing is $\frac{1}{216}$.

Answer (score 1):

216 possible cases, probability is $1/216$. Aprox $0.46  $percents

Comment: Thank you I was considering that there was 216 pillowcases but wasn't sure of how to go about finding the actual percentage. Can you show me how you did it?

Comment: @Tanya The formula for a percentage is $\frac{1}{216} \times 100$. So first we change $\frac{1}{216}$ into a decimal using a calculator, and then we multiply by $100$ to get our answer. The formula makes intuitive sense because we are looking at a proportion out of $100$ rather than a proportion out of $1$. E.g. a half chance is $0.5/1$—this is the same as $50/100 = 50\%$.